# How to get the response data from http.post

Tags: angular, rest

I'm using Angular typescript and trying to get data from the HTTP.post response.
This is my code:

```
this.http.post(
      link,
      postData,
      {responseType: 'json'}) //see remark below.
      .subscribe(responseData => {
        console.log(" Success from http post ");
        postResponse = responseData;         
        
        var temp: number = 0;        
        //temp = responseData[0].id;
      }, 
      (error: any) => {
          console.log(" Error from http post"+error)
      });
```

The response comes out successful.
The response is in the form of an array of class/json content with the following members - id, strMatrix, and retCode.
In the attached picture, you see the code and the debugger.
"Watching" responseData[0].id in the debugger shows the value "1," but the line temp = responseData[0].id; does not pass compilation.
Any ideas as to how to extract all fields?
I've worked a bit, and now I'm able to get access to the variables using the following commands:

```
let temp = <PostResult[]>responseData;
myResult.Id = temp[0].id;
```

myResult is defined at the beginning of the method in the following line:

```
var myResult : ResultsComponent = new ResultsComponent;
```

Now my issue is that within the post command, the data exists. Outside the post command i.e., after lines :

```
      (error: any) => {
          console.log(" Error from http post"+error)
      });
```

The data cease to exist.
What am I doing wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zedfw.jpg)

Comment: I've worked a bit and now I'm able to get access to the variables using the following comands :

Comment: Say to Type script the kind of data you expect received: `.subscribe((responseData:any[]) => {....}` or, if you has defined an interface `.subscribe((responseData:PostResult[]) => {....}`. NOTE: Although you indicate to Angular the type of the variable, that's not indicate that the response was really of this kind

Answer (score 0):

You don't define class properties in Angular using `var`. This is the correct way:

```js
// Declare a class property

matrixResponse: PostResult[];

constructor(){}

// Make your request
this.http.post(
      link,
      postData,
      {responseType: 'json'})
      .subscribe(responseData => {    
        this.matrixResponse = responseData;         
      }, 
      (error: any) => {
          console.log(" Error from http post"+error)
      });
```

I don't understand what you're trying to do with this: `var myResult : ResultsComponent = new ResultsComponent;`